# Como cambiar el color del borde de un Entry o un Button|python

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo esta interfaz grafica con tkinter mi pregunta es si se puede cambiar el color del borde que rodea al los Entry y a los Button pues para que tenga un mejor contraste con el fondo y quede mejor visualmente, yo supongo que no se puede y si no pues recomiendenme una libreria para crear interfaces graficas con mas libertad.

Probe con **highlightbackground** pero solo cambia el color de el placeholder del entry.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import * 


color_fondo = '#440c29'
white = 'white'


main = Tk()
main.geometry('580x440')
main.title('Ejemplo')
main.configure(bg=color_fondo)
main.resizable(0,0)


 #====FRAMES=====
 login = Frame(main, bg="#440c29")
 login.place(width=580, height=440,x=0,y=0)



#====Objetos del login====

user_placeholder = StringVar()
user_placeholder.set('Nombre  de  usuario')

password_placeholder = StringVar()
password_placeholder.set('Password')

title = Label(login,text="Prueba")
user = Entry(login)
password = Entry(login)

submit = Button(login,text="Iniciar sesion")
comprar = Button(login,text="Comprar pase")
contacto = Button(login,text="Contacto")


#==== Configuraciones de objetos de login=====

title.place(x=10,y=10, width=560, height=100)
title.config(font="Ubuntu 30 normal", fg='white', bg=color_fondo)

user.place(x=110,y= 150,width=350, height=50)
user.config(textvariable=user_placeholder, font="Ubuntu 15 normal",
        bg=color_fondo,border=5,fg=white)

password.place(x=110,y=220, width=350, height=50)
password.config(textvariable=password_placeholder, font="Ubuntu 15 normal",
            bg=color_fondo, fg=white,bd=5,)

submit.place(x=140, y=290, width=300,height=40)
submit.config(font="Ubuntu 15 normal",bg="white",fg=color_fondo)

comprar.place(x=130, y=360, width=150,height=40)
comprar.config(font="Ubuntu 15 normal",bg="white",fg=color_fondo)

contacto.place(x=300, y=360, width=150,height=40)
contacto.config(font="Ubuntu 15 normal",bg=color_fondo,fg='white',border=5)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tal vez esto pueda ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352833/no-way-to-color-the-border-of-a-tkinter-button

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible cambiar el color del borde de una entrada de texto o Entry, puede especificar su estado cuando esta enfocada o no enfocada con `highlightbackground`, el color del widget Entry será del color que usted elija mientras no esté activa, `highlightcolor` el color del widget Entry será del color que usted elija mientras esté activa o enfocada, `highlightthickness=2`, hace referencia a el nivel de bordeado del Entry, si no está presente no se verá el color del borde.

En su código sería lo siguiente:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import * 


color_fondo = '#440c29'
white = 'white'


main = Tk()
main.geometry('580x440')
main.title('Ejemplo')
main.configure(bg=color_fondo)
main.resizable(0,0)


 #====FRAMES=====
login = Frame(main, bg="#440c29")
login.place(width=580, height=440,x=0,y=0)



#====Objetos del login====

user_placeholder = StringVar()
user_placeholder.set('Nombre  de  usuario')

password_placeholder = StringVar()
password_placeholder.set('Password')

title = Label(login,text="Prueba")
user = Entry(login, highlightbackground = "green", highlightcolor= "red", highlightthickness=2) # El color del borde se especifica en el widget
password = Entry(login)

submit = Button(login,text="Iniciar sesion")
comprar = Button(login,text="Comprar pase")
contacto = Button(login,text="Contacto")


#==== Configuraciones de objetos de login=====

title.place(x=10,y=10, width=560, height=100)
title.config(font="Ubuntu 30 normal", fg='white', bg=color_fondo)

user.place(x=110,y= 150,width=350, height=50)
user.config(textvariable=user_placeholder, font="Ubuntu 15 normal",
        bg=color_fondo,border=5,fg=white)

password.place(x=110,y=220, width=350, height=50)
password.config(textvariable=password_placeholder, font="Ubuntu 15 normal",
            bg=color_fondo, fg=white,bd=5,)

submit.place(x=140, y=290, width=300,height=40)
submit.config(font="Ubuntu 15 normal",bg="white",fg=color_fondo)

comprar.place(x=130, y=360, width=150,height=40)
comprar.config(font="Ubuntu 15 normal",bg="white",fg=color_fondo)

contacto.place(x=300, y=360, width=150,height=40)
contacto.config(font="Ubuntu 15 normal",bg=color_fondo,fg='white',border=5)

main.mainloop()
```